Is there any to know how an android app collects or track device data?
I tried textme app to take trial in emulator. It gave trial few days in Ldplayer. But after few days it didnt show any trial option. I tried in another emulator it worked again for few days. Somehow it can recognize emulators. It doesnt work even you create new profiles in emulator and change android model,imei etc. I also tried magisk and android faker, but it didnt work.
So is there any way to bypass this app tracking system?
How is it tracking?

yes, purchase a full version
